# Xampp Apache server start error

Tags: apache, xampp

After adding the following rows to the httpd-vhosts.conf the xampp can't start up the Apache server. Any suggestions?

Ther Code:

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/WP"
    ServerName "Actual server name"
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/WP/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/htdocs/WP/logs/access.log" common

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have a look at this file:

C:/xampp/htdocs/WP/logs/error.log

Comment: The problem is that there is no such a file :S

Comment: "szerver"... welcome from .hu :-)

Answer (score 0):

apache\logs\error.log - is your other log file to see.